# How to use where statement?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell. I have a piece of code that checks whether an integer number is contained in a list.

```
myElem' :: Int -> [Int] -> Bool
myElem' a xs = foldl f' False xs
  where f' b x = if x==a then True else b
```

I don't understand how the code works from ‘Where’. I know that the f' is an expression and the whole sentance is used to define the f'. b should be a Boolean but why? Is the x equal to xs? Many thanks!

Comment: Note that the way it works is that this always goes through the whole list, even if the element was already found.

Comment: @Ingo This is not the case. Try `myElem' 0 [undefined, 0]` and then `myElem' 1 [undefined, 0]`. The first case returns `True` instead of giving an error, since it never evaluates `undefined` because it is after the first occurrence of `0`. Also, the where clause can be written as `f' b x = a == x || b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets go through it step by step. The type of `foldl` is

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

Your `where` statement defines the function `f'`, which takes two values and returns a third one. So all we know at that time is that `f` has the following type:

```
f' :: a -> b -> c
```

Since `if ... then A else B` needs both branches to have the same type, this concludes that your function will return a `Bool` (your first branch returns `True`). Therefore

```
f' :: a -> b -> Bool
```

But the second branch returns the first argument. So the first argument must be a `Bool` too (otherwise you couldn't use it for `foldl`, see above).

```
f' :: Bool -> b -> Bool
```

Since `x == a`, this indicates that `x` should be of the same type as `a`. If we know have a look at `myElem'`, we see that `a` is of type `Int`, and therefore your auxiliary function `f'` has type

```
f' :: Bool -> Int -> Bool
```

The `x` in the definition of `f'` is not equal to `xs`. Instead it is just another variable. `foldl` will walk through `xs` and use `f'` on all elements in order to reduce the list to one single value.